# problems installing scipy and sklearn

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I am quite new into programming and I am struggling much to install  scipy with the errors. I did not had any problems installing other libraries:

> Failed cleaning build dir for scipy

and

> Failed building wheel for scipy

With sklearn I am facing the problem :

> Failed building wheel for scikit-learn

just found this info on the web regarding this issue :

pip does not work well for Windows because the standard pip package index site, PyPI, does not yet have Windows wheels for some packages, such as SciPy.
via https://scipy.org/install.html

In case this is correct , how can I solve it ?

Comment: I've updated your tags to include [tag:scipy] and [tag:scikit-learn] and removed [tag:powershell] as there's no code in your question.

Comment: did you try using pip?

Comment: yeah i have tried it.. C:\Python\Scripts\pip install scipy . I have also checked my versions on python and numpy and everything updated

Comment: use conda (especially if you're on windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing these packages on Windows requires a compiler. Instead, I would recommend you visit Christoph Gohlke's [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), where he has already built the wheels for you.

Once you download the wheel, you can install using `pip`. For example:

```
pip install numpy‑1.12.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

An alternative is to install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

`pip install --pre --extra-index https://pypi.anaconda.org/scipy-wheels-nightly/simple scikit-learn`

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the issue and tried various solutions from the web, but all failed, so bad...

Finally, I solved it by:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

- the following way is not recommended (?)

  ```
  pip3 install --upgrade pip
  ```

#### Root cause:

- The pip tool is too old.

  - Before the upgrade, the pip version was **9.0.1** .
  - After the upgrade, the pip version is **20.0.3** .
  - Hence, you can check your pip version by

    ```
    $ pip --version  # for python2
    $ pip3 --version # for python3
    ```

    and try to upgrade the pip tool to fix it

#### Scenario:

- Dockerfile, ubuntu:16.04, ubuntu:18.04, docker build, python3

### References

- [Installing scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html)

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install python3-sklearn python3-sklearn-lib python3-sklearn-doc
  ```

  - for global, not for virtualenv