# installing pycaret library not completed due to an error

Tags: python, pycaret

I am trying to install pycaret library but gives me an error.

I have tried to update pip but nothing changed

```
  error: could not create 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\sklearn\datasets\tests\data\openml\292\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1-status-deactivated.json.gz': No such file or directory
  [end of output]note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn Failed to build scikit-learn
```

ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43477308/14648899

Answer (score 5):

What version of pycaret are you trying to install and what version of python are you using? Note that pycaret 2.3.x can not be installed in python 3.9 and above.

I would recommend installing the latest release 3.0.0rc2 which works in python 3.9

`pip install -U --pre pycaret`

Answer (score 0):

`PyCaret` is tested and supported on the following 64-bit systems:

- Python 3.6 – 3.8
- Python 3.9 for Ubuntu only
- Ubuntu 16.04 or later
- Windows 7 or late

According to the [documentation](https://pycaret.gitbook.io/docs/get-started/installation), PyCaret is **not** compatible with `sklearn >= 0.23.2`.

Other requirements are:

```
pandas 
scipy<=1.5.4 
seaborn 
matplotlib 
IPython 
joblib 
scikit-learn==0.23.2 
ipywidgets 
yellowbrick>=1.0.1 
lightgbm>=2.3.1 
plotly>=4.4.1 
wordcloud 
textblob 
cufflinks>=0.17.0 
umap-learn 
pyLDAvis 
gensim<4.0.0 
spacy<2.4.0 
nltk 
mlxtend>=0.17.0 
pyod 
pandas-profiling>=2.8.0 
kmodes>=0.10.1 
mlflow 
imbalanced-learn==0.7.0 
scikit-plot 
Boruta 
pyyaml<6.0.0 
numba<0.55
```